# Здравствуйте, я новичок в js, подскажите пожалуйста, не работает transform, сам setTimeout() работает

Tags: javascript

Вот сам код:

```html
const Scene = require('Scene');

const Animation = require('Animation');

const TimeModule = require('Time');

var fps = 30;
var speedBackground = 0.007;
const step1 = Scene.root.find("step1");

function random(min,max){
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const moveDownDriver = Animation.timeDriver({durationMilliseconds: fps, loopCount:Infinity,mirror: false});
moveDownDriver.onAfterIteration().subscribe(function(){moveBackground()});    

function moveBackground(){
    step1.transform.y = step1.transform.y.pinLastValue()-speedBackground;
    check();
}

function check(){
    if(step1.transform.y.pinLastValue()<-0.3){
       TimeModule.setTimeout(function(){ step1.transform.y = 0.3},0);
    }
}

moveDownDriver.start();
```

Вот нерабочий кусок:

```html
TimeModule.setTimeout(function(){ step1.transform.y = 0.3},0);
```

Comment: И откуда нам знать что такое `step1.transform.y`, как он должен работать и что вообще в примере происходит?

Comment: Дело в том что я пишу в скрипт для маски в Spark AR, и строка  `step1.transform.y = 0.3` должна переносить объект step1 в точку 0.3, но в setTimeout() она почему-то не работает